# itemize under sf produce a font warning

Tags: fonts, itemize, warnings

It seems that `textbullet` has no `sf` version. When itemize is in a `\sf` environment, I receive the following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbullet' on input line 14.
```

Here is a minimalist example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\sf
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Test
  \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

In particular, I was interested on doing this when the package [`txfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) is loaded, but I receive a similar warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/txss/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/txsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbullet' on input line 14.
```

I have noticed that by uploading the [`textcomp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package (before [`txfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) in the second example), I get rid of the warning.

Can somebody identify what lines in that package avoid the warning? In that case, I could just put the needed lines in my file, without uploading the full package. I guess that this package defines the missing font, but I do not know how to find the specific line that I need.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The warnings are telling you the bullet is coming from the math fonts, but since you know that but don't want to be warned, perhaps the easiest thing to do is

```
\renewcommand\textbullet{\ensuremath{\bullet}}
```

Then it will explicitly use math and not feel the need to warn you. Even simpler of course would be to ignore the warnings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\textbullet{\ensuremath{\bullet}}
\begin{document}
{\sf
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Test
  \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I still receive the warning.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz-Caro you must not have added it to the correct place, it is impossible for that definition to generate that warning, see the MWE I just added to my answer.

Comment: You are right! It seems that if I load `hyperref`, then your `renewcommand` has to be placed after it.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz-Caro: `\textbullet` is a command that is defined via NFSS2. `hyperref` uses NFSS2 to redefine the symbol for the bookmark encodings. Using `\renewcommand` puts the symbol out of the NFSS2 system and `hyperref` does not expect that a standard symbol is changed that way. Thus a better way is the redefinition via NFSS2: `\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textbullet}{\ensuremath{\bullet}}`

Answer (score 7):

The text fonts don't have a bullet character, so `\textbullet` is obtained with a font substitution: instead of `OT1/<family>/m/n/`, TeX looks for `OMS/<family>/m/n` and, if it doesn't find it, it changes `<family>` into the standard math symbol font family. Since it appears you're using Latin Modern, the process is

```
OT1/lmss/m/n
OMS/lmss/m/n
OMS/lmsy/m/n
```

because there's no `OMS/lmss` font defined and `<family>` refers to the current font family, which in your case is the one corresponding to sans serif. The same will happen with all font families that haven't a math symbol font for the sans serif family.

Note that the font substitution is performed also with the Roman font family; in the case of Computer Modern, the substitution is silent; other font families may not have defined this font substitution as silent.

There's no way to get rid of the warning, except loading `textcomp`. In that case `\textbullet` is redefined to point to a character in the TS1 encoded font

```
TS1/lmss/m/n
```

which exists and so no warning is produced.

A couple of notes. First, using `txfonts` is not recommended; better doing

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

Second, `\sf` is an obsolete command; use `\sffamily`, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I use `txfonts` and `\sf` only because this is a form that I am filling up, so I cannot modify it. I was looking at the minimum modification just to get rid of this annoying warning, but I see now that it is not possible.